# AWS EC2 t2.micro failing to load webpage throwing a 502 (MERN Application)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, mern

I set up a MERN STACK app a few weeks back on AWS EC2 it was working wonderfully until I edited a single line in python completely unrelated, after back-dating the program to the previous version, the application continues to push out status code 502.
[Here's a link to the webpage](https://ecommerce.benjaminhardwick.co.uk/) and
[Here is the error message from web page(if you don't want to click the link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYgKP.png)

I honestly have no idea what's happened here, or where to go, like I said this was working perfectly fine prior to changing a single line of unrelated code.

Further details:

- HTTPS is set up with NGINX / Route53
- PM2 is being used
- I have tried clearing node_modules and reinstalling
- I have tried reinstalling NPM/NodeJS
- Ubuntu t2.micro instance

If you are able to help me I am more than grateful - I will try to provide any details required to help conquer this problem.

PM2 logs

```
0|server  | Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
0|server  |     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1310:16)
0|server  |     at listenInCluster (node:net:1358:12)
0|server  |     at Server.listen (node:net:1445:7)
0|server  |     at Function.listen (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
0|server  |     at file:///home/ubuntu/backend/server.js:50:5
0|server  |     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:154:23)
0|server  |     at async Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:166:24)
0|server  |     at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15) {
0|server  |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|server  |   errno: -98,
0|server  |   syscall: 'listen',
0|server  |   address: '::',
0|server  |   port: 5000
0|server  | }


0|server   | Server running in production on port: 5000
0|server   | Server running in production on port: 5000
0|server   | Server running in production on port: 5000
0|server   | Server running in production on port: 5000
0|server   | Server running in production on port: 5000
0|server   | Server running in production on port: 5000
0|server   | Server running in production on port: 5000
0|server   | GET /index.html 200 0.694 ms - 2735
0|server   | Server running in production on port: 5000
0|server   | GET /index.html 200 0.689 ms - 2735
0|server   | GET /static/js/2.18e5d696.chunk.js 304 1.058 ms - -
0|server   | GET /static/js/main.6eb24991.chunk.js 200 0.731 ms - 86367
0|server   | GET /HARDWICKSLOGOWHITE.png 200 0.709 ms - 142845
0|server   | GET /index.html 304 0.442 ms - -
0|server   | GET /HARDWICKS_LOGO.png 200 0.737 ms - 27907


   listen         80 default_server;
   listen         443 ssl http2 default_server;
   listen         [::]:80 default_server;
   listen         [::]:443 ssl default_server;
   server_name    ecommerce.benjaminhardwick.co.uk;

   ssl_ciphers aNULL;
   ssl_certificate data:$empty;
   ssl_certificate_key data:$empty;

location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:443;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}

~
```

conf.d

```
server {
    #listen<200b>       443;
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server;
    server_name ecommerce.benjaminhardwick.co.uk;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/frontend/server_logs/host.access.log main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        root   /home/ubuntu/frontend/deploy;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    server_tokens off;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

}
~
```

Error logs: after fixing pm2

```
0|server  | GET /manifest.json 304 0.414 ms - -
0|server  | GET /HARDWICKS_LOGO.png 304 0.327 ms - -
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.679 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /static/js/2.18e5d696.chunk.js 200 0.680 ms - 300572
0|server  | GET /static/js/main.6eb24991.chunk.js 200 0.655 ms - 86367
0|server  | GET /HARDWICKSLOGOWHITE.png 200 0.659 ms - 142845
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.637 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /HARDWICKS_LOGO.png 200 0.649 ms - 27907
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.658 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.703 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.680 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.646 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /static/js/main.6eb24991.chunk.js 304 0.460 ms - -
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.639 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /static/js/2.18e5d696.chunk.js 200 0.649 ms - 300572
0|server  | GET /static/js/main.6eb24991.chunk.js 200 0.649 ms - 86367
0|server  | GET /static/js/main.6eb24991.chunk.js.map 200 0.662 ms - 235548
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.624 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /HARDWICKS_LOGO.png 200 0.647 ms - 27907
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.658 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.644 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /static/js/2.18e5d696.chunk.js 304 0.420 ms - -
0|server  | GET /static/js/main.6eb24991.chunk.js 200 0.651 ms - 86367
0|server  | GET /index.html 304 0.423 ms - -
0|server  | GET /HARDWICKS_LOGO.png 200 0.577 ms - 27907
0|server  | GET /manifest.json 304 0.402 ms - -
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.628 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /index.html 304 0.430 ms - -
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.647 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.641 ms - 2735
0|server  | GET /index.html 200 0.626 ms - 2735
```

Proxy pass /sites-available/default

```
   server {
   listen     80 default_server;
   listen         443 ssl http2 default_server;
   listen     [::]:80 default_server;
   listen         [::]:443 ssl default_server;
   server_name    ecommerce.benjaminhardwick.co.uk;

   ssl_ciphers aNULL;
   ssl_certificate data:$empty;
   ssl_certificate_key data:$empty;

location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:443;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232403/discussion-on-question-by-benjamin-aws-ec2-t2-micro-failing-to-load-webpage-thro).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your log file..

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

Node is not running, it tries to start on port 5000 but there is already an app running on 5000.

Meaning NGINX is trying to proxy to your backend app but its not running.